# SQL-Server Error Could not find method 'STContains'

Tags: sql-server, database, geospatial

I'm using the mssql server to implement a spatial database. I have one table (**Ways**) containing a geography column called **geoline**, that is of **LINESTRING** type.

I want to select the geoline containing a specific POINT, with the coordinates (38.731611,-9.135336).

I tried this:

```
SELECT  geoLine.STAsText() 
FROM Ways 
WHERE geoLine.STContains(geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(38.731611 -9.135336)', 0));
```

But it returned the following error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 An expression of non-boolean type
>   specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'.

What can I do? Any idea for a success query?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using SQL SERVER 2008 or below thats why you are getting that error because
`STContains (geography Data Type)` will work from `SQL SERVER 2012` and above ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929274.aspx)).

In your case to find instance completely contains another geometry instance you need a `geometry data type`.

**[FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc2b1b/2)**

```
CREATE TABLE #Ways
  (geoLine GEOMETRY)

INSERT INTO #Ways
            (geoLine)
VALUES      (geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)', 0)),
            (geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(38.731611 -9.135336)', 0))

SELECT geoLine.STAsText() AS geoLine,geoLine
FROM   #Ways

SELECT geoLine.STAsText() AS geoLine
FROM   #Ways
WHERE  geoLine.STContains(geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(38.731611 -9.135336)', 0)) = 1
```

Comment: @jpw I think Problem is geoLine is of Geography type so there may be operand type clash. STCONTAINS test two geometry instances to see if the first instance contains the second instance.

Comment: Indeed. The OP should probably use STIntersects or something similar.

Comment: @Pradeep - Yes, geoLine is of type geography.. Perharps it could be the problem!
I'm changing it's type and I'll try your query ;)

Comment: @Pradeep, it returns this error:
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.ArgumentException: 24144: This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a geometry instance to shift slightly.
System.ArgumentException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.ThrowIfInvalid()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.STContains(SqlGeometry other)

Comment: @CarlosPiedade Dono y you are getting such error. check the code now. added demo too.

Answer (score 2):

According to [T-SQL documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933904.aspx), `STContains` returns a `BIT` data type, so your `WHERE` condition should look like this I think :

```
SELECT  geoLine.STAsText() 
FROM Ways 
WHERE geoLine.STContains(geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(38.731611 -9.135336)', 0)) = 1;
```

Comment: I tried now, but it returns this error:
"Msg 6506, Level 16, State 10, Line 3
Could not find method 'STContains' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' "

Comment: Hummm, I can't say for that one, sorry.

Comment: Humm tanks my friend.. Is that any problem about geoLine beeing of the type geography and the Point in here of the type geometry?

Comment: Yes, you can't mix geometry and geography types. If geoLine is of type geography try casting it to geometry.